# How can I improve the performance of my VBA code to avoid "procedure too large"?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am struggling to avoid "procedure too large" in my VBA code.

My code has to assign a specific category to a material code based on description and some other variables.
I am using a lot of Select Case/Cases and if's to do this, recently I've tried to add collections and use a for each item in collection but it badly decreased the performance of my code.

My code is 2000-3000 lines.
Please find below part of my code just so you can understand what I'm dealing with:
collection code:

```
Function CollectionMarketing()

Dim coll As New Collection
Dim collString As String

    coll.Add " data sheet"
    coll.Add " brochure"
    coll.Add " film box"
    coll.Add " data sheet"
    coll.Add " value coin"
    coll.Add " pictogra"
    coll.Add " poster"
    coll.Add " target group"
    coll.Add " flyer"
    coll.Add " blazer"
    coll.Add " pants"
    coll.Add " shirt"
    coll.Add " jacket"
    coll.Add " vest"
    coll.Add " wk overal"
    coll.Add " coat siz"
    coll.Add " dungarees"
    coll.Add " boots size"
    coll.Add " usb stick"
    coll.Add " fossil"
    coll.Add " running"
    coll.Add " blous"
    coll.Add " hoodie"
    coll.Add " shoe siz"
    coll.Add " motif"
    coll.Add " calendar"
    coll.Add " bookl"
    coll.Add " greeting"
    coll.Add " chirstmas"
    coll.Add " catalogue"
    coll.Add " illustrate"
    coll.Add " flopo"
    coll.Add " campaig"
    coll.Add " dvd "
    coll.Add " highlight"
    coll.Add " cash box"
    coll.Add " lenticul"
    coll.Add " sales"
    coll.Add " vinyl"
    coll.Add " magazine"
    coll.Add " broschüre"
    coll.Add " general term"
    coll.Add " boots"

   Set CollectionMarketing = coll

End Function
```

Repetitive code with different string:

```
'Cellulose filter
                Case StrCheck(strng, " cartridge filte") Or StrCheck(strng, " cellulose") Or StrCheck(strng, " filter sponge")
                   If StrCheck(strng, "PES") = True Or StrCheck(strng, " PE ") = True Then ' PES Filter here
                       objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A03"
                   Else
                    objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A02"
                   End If

            'HEPA filter
             Case StrCheck(strng, " hepa") And StrCheck(strng, " filter")
                objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A08"

            'Other air filters
             Case StrCheck(strng, " pocket filte") Or StrCheck(strng, " filter cone") Or StrCheck(strng, " filter tower") Or StrCheck(strng, " demister filter ")
                objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A09"


            'Glass fibre flat fil
            Case StrCheck(strng, " flat pleated filt") Or StrCheck(strng, " flat filte")
                objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A10"
```

For each loop code:

```
 Dim coll As Collection
 Dim collString As String
 Dim item As Variant
 Dim flg_coll As Boolean

' Set the line status to "processing..."
objSheet.Cells(iRow, 3) = 1

Set coll = CollectionMarketing
    For Each item In coll
        collString = item



 For i_count = 0 To 10
```

.
.
.
repetitive code here
.

```
Case StrCheck(strng, collString)
                     objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "S04A00"
```

.

```
             'Shafts C02C03
      Case StrCheck(strng, " shaft") Or StrCheck(strng, " axle")
        If Left(s_actualmatgr, 3) = "M01" Then
                 objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = s_actualmatgr
        Else
        objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "C02C03"
        End If
           End Select

     'Marketing materials
  ElseIf Left(s_material, 4) = "7.00" Then
    objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "S01A03"


         'military equipment
  ElseIf Left(s_divisionagn, 5) = "54000" Then
        objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P07E00"



    End If
  End If
 s_propmatgr = objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24)

  If Left(s_propmatgr, 1) <> "" Then
    Exit For
    flg_coll = True
   End If
   Next i_count
    If flg_coll = True Then
        Exit For
        End If
     Next item

    If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg, vbCritical


' Update the Status to "completd" and exit
objSheet.Cells(iRow, 3) = 2

Exit Function

myerr:
' Update the status to "Error"
objSheet.Cells(iRow, 3) = 3
 End Function
```

Sorry for the long post, waiting your feedback how can I improve the performance or what should I use instead of collections.

Thank you,

Comment: at the risk of sounding profoundly oblivious.... have you tried breaking your code up into separate procedures and functions?  I've written applications several times larger than 3k lines and have yet to see that error, likely because my longest sub is about 100 lines.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how collections work tbh, but arrays are really lightweight and might therefore improve the performance.

Comment: where are your hard coded strings coming from?  Like in this example `Case StrCheck(strng, " hepa") And StrCheck(strng, " filter"   objSheet.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = "P00A08"'` if the strings are in your collection, in a file, or otherwise retrievable and in order so they can be looped then you can certainly condense your code

Comment: It looks very much like you should be using lookup tables in your workbook rather than hardoding all those strings into your code.

Comment: Adding to what @Rory mentioned, I don't think you even need VBA for this. From what I can see, you can achieve this with formulas

Comment: First of all thank you for you answers, some strings are hardcoded in the code by me, others are coming from a collection. I am connecting my excel file to the SAP system, looking at several variables from the masterdata then based on the description it asigns a specific string of char in the column 24, this column 24 will then be imported to the Sap system